# Refresh div by a AJAX + jQuery + Spring MVC request

Tags: ajax, spring, refresh

I dont know how to resolve this. I am using Spring MVC to resolve the views but I don't want to redirect to a new page, I just want to load the response in a `div`.

Let me explain it a bit. First I want to make an AJAX request to the Spring MVC controller that resolves the view, but I want to load that view in a `div`. I don't know if it's possible...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery's `.load( )` method:

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Thank you! And with this method, Do I still need the Ajax request? It doesn't look like. I just have to put the URL and Spring MVC do the rest, isn't it?

Comment: This uses AJAX to make the request. It still uses AJAX, but you don't need to call `$.ajax( )` or `$.get( )` or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

Call a regular handler method from jQuery (`$.get`), and replace the `<div>` html contents with the HTML coming back from the handler call.

Comment: Thank you too! And like with the other answer, I don't need to make the Ajax request, or I need it?

Comment: The `$.get` call makes the AJAX request for you